# How to access firebase hosting file from firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a simple firebase function it has to send a file in response to the request the file is in /app/one.html

my project directory structure

```
blog
|____app
      |____index.html
      |____one.html
|____functions
      |____index.js
```

I have to access one.html and send it from senFile()

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.blog = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile('app/one.html'); #here I need something to do
});
```

Comment: If u want to send `one.html` replace `index.html` with it.

Comment: okay whatever the file it may be, it should be accessed. @kgangadhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `firebase deploy` for functions deploys only the contents of functions folder. So if you move/copy your app folder to inside of functions folder you can achieve what you are trying to do.

```
blog
|____functions
      |____app
          |____index.html
          |____one.html
      |____index.js
```

After you changed the paths correctly you can send the file like an express app.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'app/one.html'));
```